# My Web App (in eclipse) works when using "Internal Web Browser" but does not work with Chrome. Are HTTP requests the cause?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

I've been using a static web project in eclipse to create this web application that makes some calls to the BandsInTown API in conjunction with GoogleMaps. It works perfectly when I use Open With>Web Browser and the web browser is set to "Internal Web Browser". However, when I switch this to chrome, everything seems to work fine at first (all the html and appearance functions correctly) but when I click the button (which calls my javascript function which contains calls to the API) nothing happens.

I looked in the Developer Tools module on Chrome and the console tab (more tools> developer tools> console) did show some errors in the API call. This is the error it throws for each call to the API:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Vince%20Staples/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=music_matcher&location=Cincinnati,OH&radius=150. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

The url in the error message is the correct url and if you follow it, it contains the exact information I want. So access is this issue. However, I'm confused by this error and how to approach fixing it. Why does this work on my internal browser but not on Chrome (or internet explorer)?

Here is the code for my http request to the API:

```
  //BandsInTown API subproject helper functions
  // HTTP GET call to BandsInTown API
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) { //theURL or a path to file
var numEvents= 0;
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);  //if you fetch a file you can JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText)

        if (callback) {
          callback(data);
        }                   
    }        
};
httpRequest.open('GET', theUrl, true); 
httpRequest.send(null);    

}
```

and

```
var HttpClient = function() {
this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
    var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
            aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
    }

    anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
    anHttpRequest.send( null );
}
}
```

and is called with

```
//extracts data from api for each artist
function parseEvent(artist, locat, showsObject) {
var url = 'http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/' + artist + '/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=music_matcher&location=' + locat + '&radius=150';


var showCount = httpGetAsync(url, function(data) {
    var numEvents = Object.keys(data).length;       
    for (var j = 0; j < numEvents; j++) {

        if (!(data[j].venue.latitude == null && data[j].venue.latitude == 'undefined')) {
            var element = 
             { 
                "location": {"latitude": data[j].venue.latitude, "longitude": data[j].venue.longitude},
                "artist": data[j].artists[0].name,
                "venue_name": data[j].venue.place,
                "date": data[j].datetime,
                "ticket_url": data[j].ticket_url,
                "ticket_status": data[j].ticket_status,
                "title": data[j].title
            };

            showsObject.push(element);
            }   
    }

}); 

return showsObject.length;
}
```

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` - you have a CORS problem, the server doesn't want you using resources from it - not sure what this `internal browser` is and why it doesn't follow the security measures CORS is supposed to provide

Comment: @Jaromanda X 7 is this something I can fix in my code? Or is this a problem on the api's side?

Comment: api side, though you map be able to bypass the problem by using your server to "proxy" requests to the API